# Where can I get annotated data set for training date and time NER in opennlp?

Tags: data-request, machine-learning, nlp

I need to build a model to extract the calendar event information from text format. The model should be able to detect the data and time in any format. Is there any annotated data set for data and time finder in all possible formats?

Answer (score 1):

Here a list of datasets for NER, some tagged times and dates: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/7280/1652