# Creating NER Tagging Benchmark Corpus

Tags: machine-learning, nlp

I am trying to test one name entity tagger. 
I am using NLTK's `nltk.HiddenMarkovModelTagger.train(trains)`
which requires data in Brown corpus's tagged_sents() format.

I was looking for a free benchmark entity tagged corpus in the said
format of Brown corpus.

I could not find anyone.

I found conll2000 in NLTK itself from which I am trying to extract data 
as (w,c) format as in http://pastebin.com/AttNEbSe and test.

I am thinking of an alternative. 
I found two online NERs, like 
Stanford Online NER
Cognitive Computing Group NER

If I paste data generate NER like http://pastebin.com/x1bVW6u7
and create data in said format, may I use either of them as benchmark data?

Please suggest

Comment: Tagging is very expensive and only a few institutions can afford it. I doubt that you will find a free alternative or a free Brown-like corpus.

Comment: I understand it. I am trying to produce sizeable data to do Benchmark tests at present. Full corpus I can not work out this way. If I need that I may have to talk with my Corpus Linguistics friends.

Comment: Maybe [this question](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/7250/corpus-of-tagged-text-english-newspapers-or-any-tagged-text) can help you.

Comment: Thanks for your time and effort. I posted this question after going through that link. Don't worry my local ML fraternity verified I am right if I create benchmark test data in this way.